# How to change activities attributes at manifest file using gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

My manifest file is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.com.myapplication"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I need to remove `android:configChanges="orientation"` and        `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for `debug` buildType.

How can I do it using gradle?

**P.S.** I know that I can have 2 different manifest files. But I need to have one (its easy to forgot to add an activity to one of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to solve it is to use manifest placeholders:

1) Change manifest like:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="${configChanges}"
            android:screenOrientation="${screenOrientation}"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

2) add manifest placeholders at gradle:

```
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ screenOrientation:"portrait", configChanges:"orientation"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ screenOrientation:"unspecified", configChanges:""]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can define `resValue` in you debug and release config, for example:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    resValue "string", "screenOrientation" , "landscape"
}
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    debuggable true
    resValue "string", "screenOrientation" , "portrait"
}
```

and than you can access the value from AndroidManifest `android:screenOrientation="@string/screenOrientation`

Comment: cannot set string resource to `android:screenOrientation`, also cannot set resource to `android:configChanges`